# sed + remove the first directory from path

Tags: shell-script, sed, filenames

I need to remove the first directory from a path by `sed`,
(the inverse pf what `basename` does).

For example

```
echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | sed ...
```

I should get:

```
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | sed 's|^/[^/]*||'
```

which gave me:

```
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

It looks for the first `/` followed by as many non-`/`s as possible, then replaces them with an empty string.

Comment: Is there need to escape? `sed 's,^/[^/]*,,'` works fine to me.

Comment: Probably not - I tend to escape and quote everything to be on the safe side :-) I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3):

In a POSIX shell:

```
$ x='/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt'
$ printf "/%s\n" "${x#/*/}"
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

**Explanation**

The [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) `${x#/*/}` removes the leading component of the path with the two `/`s enclosing it and the `printf` tacks a leading `/` back on.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to remove the shortest string of non-`/` characters from the beginning of the string.

In most regular expression languages, `[ ]` os a character class that matches anything within the brackets. `[abc]` will match either `a` or `b` or `c`. `[^ ]` is a *negated* character class, matching anything except the characters in it. So, `[^/]*` will match the longest string of non-`/` characters. A `^` at the beginning of a regular expression makes it match only at the beginning of the input string. Combining these, you can do:

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | sed 's/^\/[^/]*//'
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

Or, you can set the input field delimiter of awk to `/` and print everything but the last field:

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | 
    awk -F/ '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){printf "/%s",$i};print ""}'
```

Or you could use some Perl trickery:

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | 
    perl -F/ -lane 'print "/",join "/",@F[2..$#F]'
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

or, some better Perl trickery [as suggested by @Joseph R.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145057/sed-remove-the-first-directory-from-path/145062?noredirect=1#comment233855_145062):

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | perl -pe 
   perl -pe 's{^/.*?(?=/)}{}'
```

or even simply:

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | perl -pe 's#/[^/]+/#/#'
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

Finally, you could also use the power of Perl regular expressions with `grep`:

```
$ echo "/mnt/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt" | grep -oP '/[^/]+?\K/.*'
/VPfig/Amer/AR4/Celtel/files/COM.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Perl trickery just make use of the superior Perl regexes? `echo ... | perl -pe 's{^/.*?(?=/)}{}'`

Comment: @JosephR. yes it should, thanks. Answer edited.